# Upload file to google drive via R

Tags: r

I have a task to upload excel files to disk.
That is, there is a link to the drive like https://drive.google.com/drive/u/1/folders/1RB_9wvdu2mos6lCMpQqiTF0c
and files on the computer

I found the googlesheets library but I don’t fully understand how to use, for example, the function drive_upload to do what I need

setwd() to drive does not working either

Comment: Are you trying to copy data from computer into an existing google sheet? into a new google sheet? Or are you trying to download data from a google sheet to your local computer? If you're having trouble using `drive_upload`, I suggest that if you share the code you have tried, we can fix it a little more directly. (Because of your mention of `setwd()`, I suggest you include the result of `getwd()` and the location of local files you're trying to access.)

Comment: i tried setwd("https://drive.google.com/drive/u/1/folders/1RB_9wvdummmCMpQqiCT09O6t8TF0c") but it returns error "cannot change working directory"

Comment: `setwd` only works for local drives. If you are using google drive for desktop (a program that syncs a *local* folder such as `c:/Users/you/mygoogledrive` with your google drive), then you can do `setwd("c:/Users/you/mygoogledrive")` and do things that way. But that is *not at all required* in order to read files in that location: all operations on files that are in the current directory can work just fine on files that are in another directory, though occasionally with a caveat or additional argument. (Based on your mention of `drive_upload`, though, I think this is the wrong path.)

Comment: But your problem is still under-defined. Regardless, `googlesheets` is deprecated in lieu of [`googlesheets4`](https://googlesheets4.tidyverse.org/). Read that page. Make sure you can [authenticate](https://googlesheets4.tidyverse.org/articles/auth.html) properly. Then read the examples in the [`read_sheet`](https://googlesheets4.tidyverse.org/reference/range_read.html) documentation.

Comment: @r2evans so there is no way to upload files directly to cloud and not using local storages or software (as Google drive application) ?

Comment: Have you attempted to use [`googlesheets4::sheet_write`](https://googlesheets4.tidyverse.org/reference/sheet_write.html)? It appears to be intended to do just that: write data to a google worksheet, and it operates on `data`, not `file_path_on_local_disk`.